# Node attribute evalution

Tags: chef-infra

I had this strange issue

```
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `split' for 3:Fixnum

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/maven/attributes/default.rb:27:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/maven/attributes/default.rb:

 20:  # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 21:  # limitations under the License.
 22:  #
 23:  
 24:  default['maven']['m2_home'] = '/usr/local/maven'
 25:  default['maven']['mavenrc']['opts'] = '-Dmaven.repo.local=$HOME/.m2/repository -Xmx384m'
 26:  default['maven']['version'] = '3.3.3'
 27>> default['maven']['url'] = "http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/maven/maven-#{node['maven']['version'].split('.')[0]}/#{node['maven']['version']}/binaries/apache-maven-#{node['maven']['version']}-bin.tar.gz"
```

Line 26 defines the attribute as '3.3.3', which is string and the split should have worked.

When I checked the node, it had a value

```
maven
    version : 3
```

I changed this value to

```
'3.3.3'
```

And now the recipe could run successfully.

I was assuming the node attributes are evaluated and then set to the node. Why did I face this issue and how did the change in value fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably used `knife node edit` or a similar command at some time in the past. Those attributes set directly on the node are permanent, and above `default` in priority so it would have shadowed your default attribute from the cookbook. You can use `knife node edit` again to simply remove that attribute from the node's `normal` section and the cookbook default will take over.

Comment: Awesome! that was the missing piece :) Would you know how did these normal attributes got in? like what is the way other than knife node edit? Thanks a lot again

Comment: If you use `node.set` in a recipe, it does the same thing.